# PHP Curl Do While Loop on Pagination with Limit and Offset

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, pagination

I am newbie here and want to ask about PHP loop

I want to get 'itemid' from myendpoint and store it to `$result_array`

Myendpoint has pagination

First page, `offset=0`, second page, `offset=100`, etc

Maximum itemid on first page is 100, second page is 100, etc

The last page is unknown, so I set `count($result_array) % 100 == 0` as while condition

The logic is if first page contain 100 itemid, do second page, if second page contain 100 itemid, do third page, etc

My script only work if first page contain < 100 itemid and there is no second page

How to solve this?

Thank you.

this is my script:

```
$limit = 100;
$offset = 0;

$result_array = array();

$url = 'https://myendpoint/?limit=' . $limit . '&offset=' . $offset;

do {

   $ch = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

   $response = curl_exec($ch);

   $data = json_decode($response, true);

   curl_close($ch);

   $itemIds = array();
   foreach ($data["items"] as $row) {
       $itemIds[] = $row["itemid"];
   }

   $result_array = array_merge($result_array, $itemIds);

   $offset = $offset + $limit;

} while (count($result_array) % 100 == 0);

print_r($result_array);
```

Comment: What have you tried to check why the script does not work for more items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple error: you use the same URL over and over, as you build it outside your loop. Move it into your loop, such that it contains the `$offset` you are calculating within that loop